# Can't Install MySQL after stupid clash with mariaDB

Tags: dpkg, mysql, dependencies, mariadb

It completely slipped my mind that MySQL was already installed on this particular computer and I installed MariaDB, I was also unaware of the consequences of having both packages on the same computer, I've been trying to uninstall completely both installations and remove dependencies for both of them.
I've looked online for several tutorials on how to do this and I am still having trouble running MySQL, below you will find screen captures of the terminal window as well as a list of many of the attempted solutions I have tried, unfortunately I have attempted so many that I am unable to recall the order in which I have tried them, I only want to have a working installation of MySQL but somehow there is something I am unable to remove from the previous installations and MySQL installation is not working, I get dpkg: warnings. Any and all help will be extremely appreciated. (Ubuntu 20.04)

This is a screen capture of the terminal window.

```
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ ps ax | grep mysql
   4958 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ sudo mysql_secure_installation utility
[sudo] password for homeserver: 

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ sudo systemctl stop mysql
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ sudo systemctl stop mysql
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ sudo apt install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
synaptic is already the newest version (0.84.6ubuntu5).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  hplip-data printer-driver-postscript-hp python3-renderpm
  python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.

homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ sudo service mysql restart
[sudo] password for homeserver: 
Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ apt search mysql | grep "\[install"
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
libdbi-perl/focal,now 1.643-1 amd64 [installed]
libmysqlclient21/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
librdf0/focal,now 1.0.17-1.1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mysql-client-8.0/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
mysql-client-core-8.0/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
mysql-common/focal,focal,now 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 all [installed]
mysql-server/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security,now 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed]
mysql-server-8.0/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
mysql-server-core-8.0/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
rsyslog/focal,now 8.2001.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ sudo apt -f install mysql-server
[sudo] password for homeserver: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ sudo apt -f install mysql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-client
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 9.424 B of archives.
After this operation, 110 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 mysql-client all 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [9.424 B]
Fetched 9.424 B in 1s (14,4 kB/s)       
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-server-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client-core-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-server-core-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 223970 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client_8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ dir
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ cd ..
homeserver@ubuserv:~$ dir
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  snap  Templates  Videos
homeserver@ubuserv:~$ cd Downloads
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Downloads$ dir
bprocessor-M11.zip    ClientBridgeWorking.bin        RepeaterBridgeWorking3.bin
ClientBridgeWorking2.bin  mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb  teamviewer_15.5.3_amd64.deb
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-apt-config.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-server-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client-core-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-server-core-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 223974 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.15-1) ...
Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.15-1) ...
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
OK
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Downloads$ sudo service mysql status
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Downloads$ sudo service mysql start
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -P mysql
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove mysql which isn't installed
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 9.540 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 [9.540 B]
Fetched 9.540 B in 1s (17,6 kB/s)       
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-server-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client-core-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-server-core-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client-8.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 223979 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) over (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
```

SU terminal

```
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ sudo apt install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
synaptic is already the newest version (0.84.6ubuntu5).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  hplip-data printer-driver-postscript-hp python3-renderpm
  python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ synaptic
homeserver@ubuserv:~/Desktop$ sudo su
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# synaptic
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# gksu synaptic

Command 'gksu' not found, did you mean:

  command 'gosu' from deb gosu (1.10-1)
  command 'ksu' from deb heimdal-clients (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1)
  command 'ksu' from deb krb5-user (1.17-6ubuntu4)

Try: apt install <deb name>

root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# gksu synaptic

Command 'gksu' not found, did you mean:

  command 'ksu' from deb heimdal-clients (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1)
  command 'ksu' from deb krb5-user (1.17-6ubuntu4)
  command 'gosu' from deb gosu (1.10-1)

Try: apt install <deb name>

root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# synaptic admin://
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# xhost +si:localuser:root
localuser:root being added to access control list
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# synaptic
^C
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# synaptic
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# synaptic
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# synaptic
^C
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# synaptic
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# synaptic
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# cd..
cd..: command not found
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver/Desktop# cd ..
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver# cd ..
root@ubuserv:/home# cd ..
root@ubuserv:/# cd ..
root@ubuserv:/# dir
bin    dev   lib    libx32  mnt   root  snap      sys  var
boot   etc   lib32  lost+found  opt   run   srv       tmp
cdrom  home  lib64  media   proc  sbin  swapfile  usr
root@ubuserv:/# sudo aptitude install mysql-server
sudo: aptitude: command not found
root@ubuserv:/# sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
root@ubuserv:/#
```

Commands issued at the terminal

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation
$ sudo mysql
$ sudo apt remove mysql-server
$ sudo apt install mariadb-server
$ sudo nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
$ sudo service mysql restart
$ sudo service mysql stop
$ sudo service mysql start
$ systemctl status mariadb.service
$ set mysql/config/mysqld/innodb_force_recovery=1
$ systemctl start mariadb
$ find /etc -name *.cnf
$ sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep mariadb
$ sudo nano /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation
$ apt-get purge mysql-server\*
$ rm -rf /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
$ sudo apt-get purge mysql*
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
$ sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
$ sudo apt-get remove ––purge mariadb-server
$ del mysql*
$ rm mysql*
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ ps -A|grep mysql
$ sudo pkill mysql
$ ps -A|grep mysqld
$ ps ax | grep mysql
$ sudo nano sources.list
$ sudo apt purge mariadb-*
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/share/mysql/
$ find mariadb.repo
$ find mariadb*
$ apt search mysql | grep "\[install"
$ sudo apt -f install mysql-server
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
```

Commands issued as SU

```
# service mysql stop
# killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
# apt-get --yes purge mysql-server mysql-client
# apt-get --yes autoremove --purge
# apt-get autoclean
# deluser --remove-home mysql
# delgroup mysql
# rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql* /var/log/upstart/mysql.log* /var/run/mysqld
# updatedb
# rm ~/.mysql_history
# sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server
# sudo dpkg -l | grep mariadb
# sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server 
# sudo dpkg -l | grep mariadb 
# edit /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
# killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
# apt-get --yes purge mysql-server mysql-client
# apt-get --yes autoremove --purge
# apt-get autoclean
# deluser --remove-home mysql
# delgroup mysql
# apt-get remove --purge mariadb
# apt-get remove --purge mariadb*
# sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
# sudo apt install mysql-server
# sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get --force-yes remove mysql-community-server-dbgsym mysql-community-server mysql-server
# xhost +si:localuser:root
# synaptic
```

UPDATE

I have removed Libmysqlclient21 in synaptic since it appeared as broken, attempted to uninstall MySQL successfully from synaptic and reinstall it from synaptic unsuccessfully, apparently there is a running MySQL process that I can't find, which prevents the installation of mysql-server-8.0 (mysql-client, client-8.0, client-core-8.0, server and server-core-8.0 reinstall just fine).
Following you will find the screen capture
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/pJCxYm5K2w/

Also---

```
internal Error, No file name for mysql-server:amd64
```

Comment: I did update and upgrade, the reason it is not here is that the list of commands was created by the brute force method, copy and paste line by line, and I skipped a few, thanks for the reply.

Comment: What `dpkg` error (or other error) do you currently have?

Comment: The errors are: dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-server-8.0' missing
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-common' missing
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client-core-8.0' missing
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-server-core-8.0' missing
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client-8.0' missing

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-client-8.0 but 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: mysql-client-core-8.0 but 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: mysql-server-8.0 but 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: mysql-server-core-8.0 but 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: I don't understand this, but when uninstalling, I get root@ubuserv:/# sudo apt uninstall mysql-server-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0 mysql-client-8.0
E: Invalid operation uninstall

Comment: We can use https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ Also, we can [continue the discussion here in the chat area](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108469/discussion-between-mchid-and-mario) as extended dialog in the comment section adds noise to the site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what happened, I was accessing the ubuntu machine remotely through a user account with full administrative privileges, but it was not the account created at the time of installing ubuntu, now I have finally accessed the computer directly and login in with the original account and much to my surprise, when I attempted to uninstall all of MySQL trough synaptic, I didn't get warnings or errors at all, just to play it on the safe side I run the following commands

```
# sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common -y
# sudo apt-get autoremove -y
# rm -rf /etc/mysql
# sudo find / -iname 'mysql*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
# apt --fix-broken install
```

no errors or warnings at all, so I launched synaptic and reinstalled mysql-server (synaptic took care of the dependencies) and the installation finished correctly.
This makes no sense to me since a user account with full administrative privileges should have full access, but there yo have it, MySQL is installed and running

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it looks like the MySQL APT repository provides `mysql-common` so uninstall all the native 8.0 versions but they recommend you don't purge here, just uninstall:

```
sudo apt remove mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0 mysql-server-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-client-8.0
```

Then, you should be able to do the installation:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" mysql-community-client-core mysql-community-server-core mysql-common mysql-client mysql-server
```

Finally, you can update your shared libraries by running the following command:

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient21
```

This will replace the existing version.

A list of available packages and more information can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-available).

Comment: When attempting to uninstall I get: root@ubuserv:/# sudo apt uninstall mysql-server-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0 mysql-client-8.0
E: Invalid operation uninstall

Comment: @Mario Okay. I edited the answer. Please post any future errors if there are any. Thanks.

Comment: After the Remove command I get a Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1), Should I ignore it and carry on  with reinstalling?

Comment: Also, I added `mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0` to the remove command and I added  `mysql-community-client-core mysql-community-server-core` to the install command.

Comment: @Mario Can you scroll up and see what the error is from? Maybe a missing or conflicting file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108469/discussion-between-mchid-and-mario).